# I am not able 301 redirect domain.tld/?cur=usd to domain.tld

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I try to redirect `domain.tld/?cur=usd` to `domain.tld` (there are many curencies, this is only example of one currency - we do not use anymore this solution).
I need to redirect only home with parameter to home without parameter. The other urls worked for me, I'm just having trouble getting work with that one.

I try to search and use online generators but none of the solutions work.
Here is what I am trying:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)cur\=(.*)($|&)
RewriteRule ^$ /? [L,R=301]
```

// update
before this rule I have only

```
#bof redirects
RewriteEngine enabled
```

...and then there are redirects for other URLs, but I tested this rule separately first and the result was the same...

It not redirect me.
Thanks for the help and maybe an explanation of what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: By itself that rule should work (albeit a little verbose for what you are doing). However, the order of directives in the `.htaccess` file is important - you may have a conflict. Please update your question with your complete `.htaccess` file.

Comment: "`RewriteEngine enabled`" - That's an error, it should be `RewriteEngine On`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)cur\=(.*)($|&)
> RewriteRule ^$ /? [L,R=301]
> ```

As mentioned in comments, this should already do as you require, providing there are no conflicts with other directives in the `.htaccess` file.

However, the regex in the preceding condition is excessively verbose for what you are trying to achieve (ie. just testing for the presence of the `cur` URL parameter).

If you simply want to check for the `cur` URL parameter anywhere in the query string then the regex `(^|&)cur=` would suffice (and is more efficient). No need to backslash-escape the literal `=`. And if the URL parameter always appears at the start of the query string then just use `^cur=`.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem - it was something with the hosting, after a reboot everything started working as expected.

So I can confirm that this rule is fine.

Sorry for question.